# how can i pass parameters to qnetworkrequest get method?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to pass a parameter to the `qnetworkrequest` GET method

For POST method i do

```
m_network = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(url);
QByteArray postData;
postData.append("username=...");
postData.append("password=...");
m_network->post(request,postData);
```

How can I pass a parameter to the GET method?

Is this:

```
 request.setRawHeader("ticket",".." );
```

the right way to do that?

Comment: Is that some header you want to set?

Answer (score -2):

i dont think so but i didnt find something appropriate..

i am trying to transform a java code to c++
in java the code is

```
final GetMethod get = new GetMethod(uri);        
get.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[]{ new NameValuePair("alpha", string_alpha) });
client.executeMethod(get);
```